# Add a user control programatically with WPF Prism and MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, loader

I am creating a small app using WPF, Prism and MVVM. There is a control (a loader) that I would like to reuse each time a command is being executed and I would like to place that user control on top of a certain region with some transparency. 
Namely, the region where the current module which calls the command.

How can I add this User control on top of a certain region from the ViewModel(is this the right place?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct that with Prism, the best way to do this is with **[regions](http://www.developmentalmadness.com/archive/2009/10/14/mvvm-and-prism-101-ndash-part-3-regions.aspx)**.

Just create the region in your view, give it a unique name.

```
<ContentControl rgn:RegionManager.RegionName="TopRegion" />
```

Then, in the ViewModel use the **[RegionManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.regions.regionmanager%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)** to add the usercontrol.

```
IRegion myRegion = regionManager.Regions["TopRegion"];
myRegion.Add(userControl1);
```

I should also point out that since this is in MVVM, you should probably want to add the usercontrol using some kind of IoC such as [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) or Unity.